# как преобразовать объект в query string?

Tags: javascript, функции, foreach

есть объект, мне нужно преобразовать его в query string, присвоить переменной и вывести в консоль.
мой способ не работает

```
let array = {name: "ivan", age: 15, sex: 1, id: 45}

function t10() {

    let queryString = ""

   let res = array.forEach(item =>{
       queryString += item.name + item.age + item.sex + item.id
   })
    console.log(res)
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = t10;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ваш объект можно передать параметрами в `URLSearchParams` и, приведя его к строке, получить искомый результат.

```js
let obj = {name: "ivan", age: 15, sex: 1, id: 45}

let sp = new URLSearchParams(obj);

console.log( sp.toString() )
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то имеется в виду `query string` которая передается в теле запроса к севреру, для этого нужно пройти по вхожениям (`entries`), вхождение имеет вид массива `[ключ, значение]`, дополнительно результат можно обернуть в `encodeURIComponent()` если есть русские буквы или другой юникод или символы типа `;,/?:@&=+$<>`:

```js
let object = {name: "petr&ivan", age: 15, sex: 1, id: 45}

document.write(
  (Object.entries(object)
   .reduce((acc,e,i) => 
    `${acc}${i >0 ? '&' : '?' }${e[0]}=${encodeURIComponent(e[1])}`,
    '')
  )
)
```

Comment: Экранировать кто будет?

Comment: все, поправил код)

Comment: Не, `encodeURI` - это фигня, которую вообще использовать не надо.

Comment: а что надо использовать?

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` для каждого экранируемого куска. А `encodeURI` не сможет ничего сделать, если name окажется `petr&ivan` - ivan так и останется ключом.

Comment: Нет, к вводу пользователя: `{ name: "petr&ivan" }` - должно получиться `name=petr%26ivan`, а в случае `encodeURI` получится `name=petr&ivan`, что (как минимум) испортило пользовательский ввод. Что касается экранирования именно ключей, то формально оно тоже нужно, но если ты знаешь, что используешь в них только символы, не требующие экранирования, то можно опустить. Но тут ещё привет php и некоторым фреймвёркам других языков, использующих квадратные скобки для полей-массивов, впрочем, хотя формально квадрантные скобки и требуют экранирования, без него тоже вполне работает.

Comment: Ага, плюсанул. Хотя мне мой вариант с map кажется красивее. А ещё я добавил современный вариант, где руками с экранированием заморачиваться не требуется (хотя, меня `+` вместо `%20` смущает) :)

Comment: где можно глянуть `+` вместо `%20` , ага нашел, и что оно так работает?

Comment: Не знаю, есть сомнения. Сам плюс должен заменяться на `%2B`, а пробел может на `%20` или `+`, но я никогда вариант с плюсом не использовал. `decodeURIComponent` явно не понимает, что надо менять плюс на пробел.

Comment: возможно [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) есть что-то для работы с этим

Answer (score 1):

Современный способ (хотя смущает `+` вместо `%20`):

```js
var obj = { name: "ivan petrov", age: 15, sex: 1, id: 45, ещё: "кот" }

var url = new URL("https://example.com")

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  url.searchParams.append(k, v)
}

console.log(url + "")
console.log(url.search)
```

Comment: `(new URLSearchParams(obj)).toString();`

Comment: @teran, оу, красиво. Запости ответом.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = { name: "ivan petrov", age: 15, sex: 1, id: 45, ещё: "кот" }
var qs = Object.entries(x).map(kvp => kvp.map(encodeURIComponent).join("=")).join("&")
console.log(qs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
a10 = { name: 'ivan', age: 15, sex: 1, id: 45 }

function t10() {
    let a10_res = '';
    for (key in a10) {
        a10_res += key + '=' + a10[key] + '&';
    }
    document.querySelector('.out-10').textContent = a10_res;
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = t10;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Прохожу курс из которого взято данное задание и вот решение которое я получил с учетом знаний полученных с прошлых уроков, думаю вам оно тоже подойдет

```
function t10() {
    obj = {name: 'ivan', age: 15, sex: 1, id: 45};
    let res = '';
    for (let key in a10){
        res += `${key}=${a10[key]}&`;
    }
    console.log(res);

    let example = new URLSearchParams(a10);
    console.log(example.toString());
}
```