# Из объекта в строчку для get запроса

Tags: javascript

Есть объект

```
{sf:33,22:33}
```

Предусмотрено ли в js сделать из объекта, в строчку

```
sf=33&22=33
```

Для get запроса?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1371725/178988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log(new URLSearchParams({s:123,23:44}).toString())
```

Из минусов относительно слабая поддержка старыми браузерами

Comment: Допустим есть текущий адрес страницы, он может быть с символом ? либо без. Я к тому, чтобы указать текущий url и объект с текущими параметрами. А уже к примеру URLSearchParams самостоятельно подставит параметры к текущему url, выполнив проверку на наличие ? и тд

Comment: document.URL+(document.URL.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?') Подобного рода выполняю проверку, прежде чем подставляю параметры

Comment: То есть, к текущему url добавить новые или обновить текуще параметры. Возможно?

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов менять параметры можно через URLSearchParams, просто нужно чтобы URLSearchParams был в переменной, а там уже через метод `set` меняйте и в конце всё в строчку.

Answer (score 2):

Для старых браузеров:

```js
var obj = {sf:33,22:33}
var keys = Object.keys(obj)
var output = ''

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if(i === 0) {
    output += keys[i] + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[keys[i]])
  } else {
    output += '&' + keys[i] + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[keys[i]])
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` кто использовать будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy сейчас добавлю...

Comment: Неправильно добавил...

Comment: @Qwertiy не совсем понимаю, как правильно тогда?...

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде понял...

Comment: Ага, примерно так. [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371725/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-query-string#comment2435555_1371731) подробнее обсуждалось.